# Strtofloat / Floattostr conversion

Tags: delphi

I am having an issue with the `StrToFloat` routine. I am running Delphi 7 on Windows Vista with the regional format set to German (Austria)

If I run the following code -

```
DecimalSeparator:='.';
anum:=StrToFloat('50.1123');
edt2.Text:=FloatToStr(anum);
```

when I convert the string to a float `anum` becomes 50,1123 and when I convert it back to a sting it becomes '50.1123'

How do it so that when I convert the string to a float the number appears with a decimal point rather than a comma as the decimal separator.

thanks

Colin

Comment: I'm curious to know what you are hoping to achieve here. I hope you don't want to inflict the `.` decimal separator on all your users no matter what their regional settings are.

Comment: @David - it appears when I inspect the value. I was just playing around really

Comment: @colin: Then my answer is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to appreciate the difference between a floating-point number and a textual representation of it (that is, a string of characters).

A floating-point number, as it is normally stored in a computer (e.g. in a Delphi `float` variable), does not have a decimal separator. Only a textual representation of it does. If the IDE displays the `anum` as '50,1123' this simply means that the IDE uses your computer's local regional settings when it creates a textual representation of the number inside the IDE.

In your computer's memory, the value '50.1123' (or, if you prefer, '50,1123'), is only stored using ones and zeroes. In hexadecimal notation, the number is stored as `9F AB AD D8 5F 0E 49 40` and contains no information about how it should be displayed. It is not like you can grab a magnifying glass and direct it to a RAM module to find a tiny, tiny, string '50.1123' (or '50,1123').

Of course, when you want to display the number to the user, you use `FloatToStr` which takes the number and creates a string of characters out of it. The result can be either '50.1123' or '50,1123', or something else. (In memory, these strings are `35 30 2C 31 31 32 33` and `35 30 2E 31 31 32 33` (ASCII), respectively.)

Comment: @ Andreas so I think you are saying that the IDE is just showing a ',' as I have the regional setting set to german? if I set the decimalseperator := ',' when I run the code I then get an conversion error so it must use the decimal seperator somewhere?

Comment: Yes. It has nothing to do with *your* program, only the IDE.

Comment: The decimal separator setting is only used when you turn a float into a textual representation, or when you do the opposite, namely, when you ask the computer to accept a string of characters and intepret it as a floating point number. Then, too (of course), the computer needs to know what the decimal separator character is.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I am a bit new to these things. your answer is very informative.